# ipython date attribute not found

Tags: python, pandas, ipython, jupyter-notebook

Im using ipython notebook to run some analytics using pandas. however, im running into problems with the following function and the date attributes

```
def get_date(time_unit):
    t = tickets['purchased date'].map(lambda x: x.time_unit)
    return t

# calling it like this produces this error
get_date('week')
```

**`AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'time_unit'`**

but this works without a function

```
tickets['purchased date'].map(lambda x: x.week)
```

im trying to create the function `get_date(time_unit)` because i will later need to use the function to `get_date('week')` and later `get_date('year')` etc etc.

how can i convert the string im passing to a valid attribute to use the function as i intent to use it??

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do -

```
t = tickets['purchased date'].map(lambda x: x.time_unit)
```

This would not replace whatever is inside the `time_unit` string and take `x.week` , instead it would try to take the `time_unit` attribute of x, Which is causing the error you are seeing.

You should use `getattr` to get an attribute from an object using the string name of the attribute -

```
t = tickets['purchased date'].map(lambda x: getattr(x, time_unit))
```

From [documentation of `getattr()` -](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr)

> **getattr(object, name[, default])**
>
> Return the value of the named attribute of object. name must be a string. If the string is the name of one of the object’s attributes, the result is the value of that attribute. For example, **`getattr(x, 'foobar')` is equivalent to `x.foobar`.**

Comment: oh, i was looking at setattr() but couldnt figure out how to properly use it, turns out i was using the incorrect helper.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `getattr` to retrieve the attribute by name.

```
def get_date(time_unit):
    t = tickets['purchased date'].map(lambda x: getattr(x, time_unit))
    return t

get_date('week')
```

What you were doing is equivalent to `getattr(x, 'time_unit')`.